# Why my render looks all lumpy?

Tags: rendering, light

So I made a Render animation that looks... fine for me in Blender 2.92 (first image).[image: first image: it looks fine.]

Then I decide to make the 2nd scene with a copy of the .blend archive.
The big diference between the 2 scenes is that the 2nd is like really big, I want to make somthing like the first shot of blade runner or something like that (A big shot above a futuristic city). But I don't know why the render (2nd image) looks all lumpy.
I guess is becaouse of the big scale elements, so is to many data for render and de denoiser just go crazy

-I used the denoise basic settings and the compositor denoise node. And this is the result:
[image: looks horrible.]

Comment: Denoising is not a perfect tool.  If you run more samples it has more information to work with and the splotchiness will be reduced, but the best solution is still to render with a sufficient amount of samples for the final render.

Comment: 1) Cool render! 2) yeah, that is the epitome of despising reaching its limit. More samples.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try to fix it